# MATLAB: Find first element of a cell array that belongs to another cell array

Tags: string, matlab, find, match, cell

Is there a function in MATLAB that lets me find the first element of string cell array `A` that also belongs to string cell array `B`?

I'm currently using:

```
    i = find(ismember(A,B));
    string = A{i(1)};
```

But I'd like to know if there's a function that doesn't calculate `ismember` until the last element of `A` but rather stop when finding the first match. The reason is `A` contains around 1,800,000 strings and I'm only interested in finding the first match.

Would a `for` loop be faster if I did:

```
    for j=1:length(A)
      if ismember(A{j}, B)
        string = A{j};
        break
      end
    end
```

??

Does the number of elements in `A` even influence the time required for calculating `ismember`?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if there's such a function, and I don't get why you can't do the timing tests yourself with tic/toc. Anyway, if A contains more elements than B, maybe ismember(B,A) will be faster (only when there are matches of course) ?

Comment: I can do the timing tests myself, I'm just asking in case someone already knows. Why would it be faster to do `ismember(B,A)`? I don't know because I ignore exactly what happens inside `ismember`.Thank you!

Comment: Also, if numerous strings are repeated in A, maybe **[C,ia,ic] = unique(A)** would be useful ? Not sure if it's faster though. :/

Comment: `A` is already "`unique`"

Comment: About ismember(B,A) I don't know for sure, but I guess the search for a value stops when it is met. Let's say B has two values only, with one present in the middle of A. I guess ismember(A,B) would need 1,800,000*2 searching steps, while ismember(B,A) would only require 1,800,000*1.5 steps. To sum up, if B has multiple values in A, it may go faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some optional arguments to `find` that allow you to get only the first N results.  I haven't verified that this causes short-circuit evaluation; it depends on whether MATLAB's JIT compiler is reordering operations to do `ismember` as-needed.

```
i = find(ismember(A,B), 1, 'first');
```

From [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

> `nd = find(X, k)` or `ind = find(X, k, 'first')` returns at most the first `k` indices corresponding to the nonzero entries of `X`. `k` must be a positive integer, but it can be of any numeric data type.

Your current workaround looks both straightforward and guaranteed to have the desired complexity.